# How to disable IME in a Windows UWP TextBox

Tags: windows-runtime

I want to write a pure digital textbox and I think the TextChanged event may not the best way to solve the issue. Anyone who know?

Answer (score -1):

you can set the setting IsTabStop = true on the page.

at the Begining

```
<Page
    x:Class="Salus.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Salus"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" **IsTabStop="True"** >
```

Comment: On which page? Please be specific.

Comment: On the page that contain a Textbox